# pass parameter in flex NativeProcess

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I want to pass two parameter to nativeProcess.

While i am running exe file using windows command with parameter, it is working. 
Command for window is "abc.exe a.txt b.txt"

How can I pass two parameters to the exe in that format using flex nativeProcess?

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var process:NativeProcess;
            protected function windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                if (NativeProcess.isSupported)
                {
                    callExe();
                }
                else
                {
                    textReceived.text = "NativeProcess not supported.";
                }
            }

            public function callExe():void
            {
                var a_FilePath:String = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("dist/a.txt").nativePath;
                var b_FilePath:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("dist/b.txt").nativePath;

                if (Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") > -1)
                {
                    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("dist/abc.exe");
                }

                var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
```

// i put the line below and it works in my case

**nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath();**

nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

```
                var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
                args.push(a_FilePath);
                args.push(b_FilePath);

                nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;

                process = new NativeProcess();
                process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_PROGRESS, inputProgressListener);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressEvent);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, errorData);
            }

            public function inputProgressListener(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                textReceived.text += "Input Progress Event";
            }
            public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                textReceived.text += "Output Event";
            }
            public function progressEvent(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                textReceived.text += "Progress Event";  
            }
            public function errorData(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                textReceived.text += "Error Event";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:TextInput id="textReceived" width="352" height="200"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Since there is no guarantee that you will keep the external link alive, it is preferable to copy code examples into your question. It will help other users understand this question in the future.

Comment: Many thanks for your guidance and editing. I will remember but i found my answer. I assign working directory to nativeProcess like above nativeProcessStartupInfo_Obj.workingDirectory = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(); and it was working

Comment: Then post your solution to your question as an answer and accept it please. This will also be beneficial for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my puzzle by adding the line below in bold:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var process:NativeProcess;
            protected function windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                if (NativeProcess.isSupported)
                {
                    callExe();
                }
                else
                {
                    textReceived.text = "NativeProcess not supported.";
                }
            }

            public function callExe():void
            {
                var a_FilePath:String = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("dist/a.txt").nativePath;
                var b_FilePath:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("dist/b.txt").nativePath;

                if (Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") > -1)
                {
                    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("dist/abc.exe");
                }

                var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
```

// i put the line below and it works in my case

**nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath();**

nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

```
                var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
                args.push(a_FilePath);
                args.push(b_FilePath);

                nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;

                process = new NativeProcess();
                process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_PROGRESS, inputProgressListener);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressEvent);
                process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, errorData);
            }

            public function inputProgressListener(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                textReceived.text += "Input Progress Event";
            }
            public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                textReceived.text += "Output Event";
            }
            public function progressEvent(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                textReceived.text += "Progress Event";  
            }
            public function errorData(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                textReceived.text += "Error Event";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:TextInput id="textReceived" width="352" height="200"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```